# Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, iis

Can you please assist me. I had installed IIS 7 on a Windows 7 professional 64 bit machine and I was getting errors when accessing my web pages, but now I decided to remove IIS to re-install it. The problem now is that I cannot see IIS manager in Admistrative Tools, even if I run CTLR + R (inetmgr) does not work. But when I browse http: //localhost on my browser I get the IIS7 default page as expected.

Can you please advise on what could be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to overlook, but make sure you have the following option checked.
Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Console

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that IIS is really is un-installed, and then either totally remove it or re-install it.

Open Control Panel

Program and Features

Turn Windows features on or off

Ensure that this is not checked to verify that it has been removed completely.

Comment: The author claims he is browsing to http://localhost which would indicate something is displaying the default IIS page and I highly doubt its a cache doing it.

Comment: Yes, I missed that! Updated my response, good spot, thank you @Ramhound

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response. I have indeed removed IIS components from the Turn Windows features On or Off, and seems to be removed. The problem comes when I try to re-install IIS again because I can't access inetmgr or even if I go through Administrative Tools I still don't find it. The surprising thing is that I can browse [Localhost](http://localhost) yet there is no IIS manager in admistrative Tool or even through inetmgr. @Dave and @ Ramhound

Comment: How are you installing IIS?

Comment: I went to Control Panel, then Programs, then Turn Windows features on or off, then selected Internet Information Services components.

Comment: @Teboho, can you confirm if it ever worked? It seems like it's faulty some how and you may need to repair it

Comment: Try restarting IIS Admin service